# "Fare worst" or "fare the worst"?

Tags: grammar, articles

If you need an example, you can use this one or make your own one, it doesn't matter.

> A hurricane hit the Atlantic coast. Florida fared (the) worst with estimated damages of more than $50 billion.

There's no point in an article there. None! Articles are linked to a noun (apart from cases like 'the rich', 'the poor', etc. where it makes collective nouns). Is there a noun? None! And yet, there are more search results in Google News for the second option (though still only several thousand). What I want to figure out is which option complies with the grammar rules: putting the article between 'fare' and 'worst' or not doing so? Please give a satisfactory and convincing explanation if it's the former option (I see no point in using 'the', really). As I understand it, 'worst' here modifies the verb 'fare'. The part of speech that modifies verbs is the adverb. Whether superlative adverbs take 'the' or not is unclear for me. On the one hand, in the Longman dictionary, I see this. Note that it's not classified as an idiom.

> You know him best – you should ask him.

*(from [here](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/best))*

On the other hand, on the ef.com I see this:

> Everyone in the race ran fast, but John ran **the** fastest of all.
>
> He played **the** best of any player.

*(from [here](https://www.ef.com/ca/english-resources/english-grammar/comparative-and-superlative-adverbs/))*

Now, the question is, why the ef is it so? Is it because of 'of all' and 'of any player' respectively? But in the Longman example, 'of all' is also implied.

Comment: Why can't it be seen as an adverb? As in, 'He knew her best'

Comment: Where is this sentence from? Did you write it?

Comment: @AIQ Yes. I added the missing 'than' if it's what you were implying

Comment: You are right, "worst" in this case is an adverb. With an "adverb", the superlative may or may not take an indefinite article. I agree with Astralbee. *"Superlatives are often used [with the obvious noun deleted]"*. *"A complication may be thought to arise when adverbs take the same form as adjectives"* and when, at the same time, the noun is dropped. For example, *"Florida fared the worst [of all the states] with estimated damages of ..."*. See Edwin Ashworth's answer in this ELU post: [Why do superlative adverbs sometimes use 'the'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/335031/300322).

Comment: @AIQ I don't like Edwin Ashworth's answer. It's not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the definite article *the* it should be to single something out as specific among similar peers. *The car*, for example, would be a specific car - perhaps *your* car - and it singles it out from among other cars.

When you are talking about something being *the best*, it is, therefore, being singled out as such *from among other things*.

You can say that something or someone "fares" a certain way in comparison to *themselves* and not others. In such a context, "the" would be redundant, for example:

> Companies fare best when they have a business plan.

This is not comparing one company to another - it is saying that *a* company - any company - can perform better if they have a plan, than if they don't.

It is when you are comparing how something or someone fares to others that the definite article may be necessary, for example:

> 'Company A' fared *the* best out all the companies we studied because they had a business plan.

'Company A' is a *specific' company, and it is *the best* of a group of companies studied.

In your example then, Florida fared *the worst* of all the states affected by the hurricane.

There are clearly some cases where either are idiomatic, but you've asked why it would be one or the other, so I've focused my answer on that. It might be worth you running a few examples through Google Ngrams to see which are used, which are not. For example, "fared the worst" and "fared worst" have both been used pretty evenly over time; whereas "knew him best" appears to the only idiomatic option.

Comment: 1) Please explain the 'may be' part.
2) Are 'of all', 'of any other state/company etc.' explicitly written necessary to put 'the' before an adverb?
3) Speaking of it, is it an adverb?

Comment: The question was: "A hurricane hit the Atlantic coast. **Florida fared (the) worst with estimated damages of more than $50 billion**". The point is: you cannot say "fared worst". X fared the best [of all companies] is a superlative. "X fared better than Y" is a comparative. X fared the best of all [in some situation].

Comment: 4) @Astralbee Also, please comment on the 'know best' sentence I included in my original post. It's certainly not "comparison to themselves"

Comment: This is a great answer. Its well explained and useful. Why is this downvoted?

Comment: @AIQ Why? I see the +2 score

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev I said "may be necessary" because I'm not making an arbitary rule one which to use - it depends on the context. There are clearly some cases where either are idiomatic, but you've asked why it would be one or the other, and I've focused on that. Ngrams don't tell the whole story but it might be worth you running a few examples through. "fared the worst" and "fared worst" are pretty evenly used. "Knew him best" appears to the only idiomatic option.

Comment: What do you mean by 'context'? In what context should there be the article and in which not? «"fared the worst" and "fared worst" are pretty evenly used» But I'm not interested in which option is more common. I'm interested in which option is grammatical. Still, what about the Longman example? Do you want to say that it's an idiom and hence goes without the article? But it's not marked as an idiom anyway. You also didn't answer my second and third questions

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev What I'm saying is - there are some situations where, for whatever reason, one way of saying it or the other has become idiomatic. But if you are faced with a situation where *either* seem to be used, my reasoning on whether the definite article applies can be used. I'm not avoiding any questions, I just don't see the point of walking you through any number of specific examples when there are countless more and I've cited resources you could use along with my logic

Answer (score 1):

This is a superlative adjective: the worst, the best, the funniest.

Superlatives always take the article. There is every point to an article in "Who fared the worst? To fare badly, To fare worse than some other city, to fare the worst of all the cities hit by the storm!

**And with fare, one can say it's adverbial or used adverbially to modify the verb fare**.

[superlative adjectives](https://writingexplained.org/grammar-dictionary/superlative-adjective)

Farewell! :) [a joke, but true]

Comment: Please improve your answer. Why is it not an adverb as in, 'He knew her best'? Adjectives don't modify verbs, adverbs do

Comment: Are you kidding? Are you saying that I didn't know that the superlative form of adjectives goes with 'the'? I'm arguing that adjectives don't modify verbs, adverbs do (something in my previous comment that you chose to ignore), and adverbs don't go with articles. That's also the basic fact

Comment: Wait. Do you mean it's a complement (as in, 'John got ill')?

Comment: You still didn't explain why it's an adjective and not an adverb. You just keep repeating it without doing any proving. By the way, when you said, "'to know best' is an idiomatic phrase. It is in dictionaries in that form", you were wrong. At least, in the Longman dictionary, it's not the case (https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/best)

Comment: What do you mean by 'it'?

Comment: Note that you said both 'in that form' and 'in a different form' applied to the same thing

Answer (score 1):

To me, it's a matter of using the definite article "the" with the superlative "the worst".

```
Tampa fared poorly in the storm, but Miami fared the worst.
```

Comment: You have repeated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A superlative adjective always come after "the".

> Noun (subject) + verb + the + superlative adjective + noun (object).

- Bobby talks the loudest of all the boys.
- Jill danced the best.
- Jack’s bullfrog jumped the highest.

Check out [this article](https://www.k12reader.com/term/superlative-adverbs/) for more useful information.

But with superlative adverbs, we can also choose to use 'the' or 'no article':

- Luke reads (the) fastest.
- I like vanilla ice cream (the) best.
- She can speak six languages, but she speaks Spanish (the) most 
  confidently.

So:

**- Florida fared (the) worst.**

However there are [other articles](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/superlatives.html) suggesting that sometimes we compare a person or thing in one situation with the same person or thing in a different situation. In this case, when the superlative adjective or adverb is later in the sentence, we usually don't use 'the'. Compare these two sentences:

- I'm most productive early in the morning [I'm more productive in the
  morning than I am in the afternoon or the evening].
- I'm the most productive early in the morning [I'm more productive
  than the other people in my office first thing in the morning].

Comment: What about 'best'? It goes with no 'the'. For instance, 'He couldn't decide which one he liked best' (from here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/best)

Comment: check out my edit and tell me if it answers your question. It was too long to write in a comment.

Comment: What about, 'You know him best – you should ask him' (from here: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/best)? It's certainly about the fact that "he" knows "him" better than anyone else. No 'the'!

Comment: In https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/superlatives.html it's said that: "With superlative adverbs, we can also choose to use 'the' or 'no article'." In which case I'm supposed to say sorry for wasting so much of your time instead of finishing my research first!

Comment: This is wrong. You cannot say: X fared worst in the storm. [buzzer]. It has to be: fared the worst [of all the states,for example, in the storm].